# Disputations over claims

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In clauses like "This claim is disputed." and "disputed claims", it seems that the verb "to dispute" can be used to mean that the thing we are talking about is controversial and some people disagree with it.

But in another form of the verb, disputation, it seems that (according to my searches) it does not necessarily convey that meaning (or that meaning is not common for it). What should I used instead? I want to use it in a sentence like: "The reason is that people are not aware of the existence of disputations over claims."

Comment: You haven't given enough context. The choice will depend on the nature of the **claims**. Although the words are related, the noun **disputation** usually involves a formal philosophical argument of some kind.  The verb **disputed** and the passive past participial adjective **disputed** cover a wider range of kinds of disagreement and controversy.

Comment: Consider this sentence: A lot of people believe many false claims, because they don't know there are disputations over the claims.

Answer (score 1):

Your word
[image]

seems somewhat ***academic***. Why not simply use

> The reason is that people are not aware of the existence of **disputes** over claims.

also, to say

> not aware of *the existence*

is redundant since you are later stating its *existence*.

Or alternatively you might say

> people are not aware of the **differing arguments** over claims.
>   people are not aware of the **competing viewpoints** over claims.
>   people are not aware of the **many differing sides** over claims.
>   people are not aware of the **various opinions** over claims.

Comment: This is possible. However, I sense that it does not convey what I mean. I sense that in disputations, the focus is on what is being said, but in disputes the focus is on the act of saying. For example, if I say that "it's day now" but you say "it's night" this is a dispute and "being aware of the dispute" means being aware of that you have a dispute with me (didn't believe my opinion). But if I say "being aware of the disputations" may mean that knowing what you said and what was your reasons for that.